# Is there a way to log in to the same Pokemon GO account using more than one of the sign in options?

Tags: pokemon-go

I signed up with Pokemon GO back when it first came out using my Gmail account rather than a trainer account.  However, I do also have a Pokemon Trainer Club account that shares a username with my Pokemon Go account and also is tied to the same email I used to create my Pokemon GO profile.

When I log in to Pokemon GO, it shows my username (the same username that my Trainer Club account uses) and that it's linked to my Gmail address.  Yet when I log in using the Trainer Club option, it's an entirely separate account.

Why does this happen and is there a way to be able to log in using either my Trainer Club account or my Gmail address to log in to the same account (since both accounts have the same username & same email tied to them)?

Comment: So you're saying you have two separate accounts (have different pokemon, different trainer level etc.) that share the same username? That definitely doesn't sound like an intentional feature, especially if you have the same friend code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the username of your Pokemon Trainer Club account is identical to that of your Gmail doesn't mean that they are the same account.

Your Gmail account took the name that is the name of your Trainer Club account but not the Trainer Club's PoGo-related account.

If you were to set up an account on PoGo with your Trainer Club account, you would need to give it a *different* username in PoGo to your Gmail account (since your Gmail account has reserved that name).

You cannot log into the same account with both your Gmail and Trainer Club - they can only log into separate accounts. You can, however, log into the same Gmail account with Facebook.

Also of note, [having multiple accounts is a violation of Niantic's term of service](https://nianticlabs.com/terms/en/). Using both a Gmail PoGo account and a Trainer Club PoGo account would violate this.

Comment: Niantic more or less confirmed this as well after like 10 automatic replies to support tickets.  I believe this is the correct answer.  Mind you I was not trying to have multiple accounts, just was curious about multiple ways to log in to the same one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to log onto the same account with both PTC and Gmail, if you do it correctly.  My children's accounts both are linked in this way - PTC and Gmail - as they were originally PTC accounts, and then added Gmail when this functionality was added (in 2018 I believe).

The issue here though is that I don't believe you can add a PTC login to a Gmail account.  This is how my account was set up - as a gmail account - and I am not able to add my PTC account information to it, only Facebook.

So, if you were willing to swap to using the PTC account, you could do the following:

1. Link a facebook login to your Google-login-based account
2. Unlink Google from that account
3. Link that Google account to the PTC-based account

That would allow you to have both Google and PTC-based access to the PTC account.  It would mean, however, that any pokemon you caught or any experience you gained etc. would be lost on the originally-google-based account, which it sounds like is your "primary" account.